# How to access variable express from angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, pug

first

```
exports.render = function(req,res){
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'welcome',
        username : req.user ? req.user :''
    });

};
```

I want to export **object** `req.user` to use

```
h2 Hello #{username.username}
h2 Hello #{username}
```

In Jade I can use it

```
div(ng-app='IndexController')
             {{ #{username} | getUserData }}
```

but if i want to get it to angular it can't  use

```
mainAppModule.filter('getUserData', function () {
    return function (name) {
        if (name)
            console.log(name.username + "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxqqqqqqqqqq");
        return 'Hellox, ';
    };
});
```

How can i do it? how to get `req.user` for use in future.if there is other way to get object to use in angular please tell me.
Thank so much.

Comment: your understanding of how expressions in angular work seems flawed.  `{{ #{username} }}` is going to output `{{someName}}`, which in turn means angular will be looking for a property `$scope.someName`;  it is not creating a property with the name as a value that could be consumed....

Comment: if you must do this, then you should use `ng-init`.  note that this is one of the only recommended uses for the `ng-init` directive.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.req = {'user':'scope user'};  
    
   this.req1 = {'user':'alias user'} ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as myCont">
      {{req.user}}
      <br/>
      {{myCont.req1.user}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I am not sure what problem you are facing. You can simply use $scope or controller alias to access any variable in the view.

**By Alias**

```
<div ng-controller="MainController as main">
    {{main.name.userName}}
</div>
```

**By $scope**

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    {{name.userName}}   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to pass your request object to your Angular code.

What I can suggest is try to make a module which will act as a model for jade rendered objects as below:

**index.jade**

```
div(ng-controller="myController as ctrl")
    h2 Title: {{ ctrl.title | myFilter }}
    h2 Username: {{ ctrl.username | myFilter }}
  
script.
    angular.module('jadeData',[])
      .factory('jadeDataFactory',function(){
      
        //model service to set objects retrieved from jade
        return {
          'title': "#{title}",
          'username': "#{username}"
        };
      });
script(src="/js/app.module.js")
```

Once done, you can access the service model in you main module's controller

**app.module.js**

```
  angular.module("myApp",['jadeData'])
    .controller("myController",function(jadeDataFactory){
      var that = this;
      
      that.title = jadeDataFactory.title;
      that.username = jadeDataFactory.username;
      
    })
    .filter("myFilter",function(){
      return function(v){
        if(v)
          console.log('Inside filter value: ',v);
        return v+' Modified';
      }
    });
```

This way you can inject the jadeDataFactory to any of the required controllers/services

**Explanation**: actually Jade is rendered in server side, and if you write  `{{ #{username} | getUserData }}` then renderer could not get it correctly, the better way is to store it in a service model and access it in required controller.